# Detect encoding and decode LE manufacturer data from LE scanRecord

Tags: java, android, character-encoding, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am able to get manufacturespecificdata from the ble scanrecord. But fails to guess the encoding and decode to string every time. Is there any smarter way to decode byte data  to string.

Code sample-

```
SparseArray<byte[]> manf_data = scan_record.getManufacturerSpecificData();
if (manf_data .size() != 0) {
   for (int i = 0, arraySize = manf_data.size(); i < arraySize; i++) {
     byte[] obj = man_data.get(manf_data.keyAt(i));
     String mdata = new String(obj, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
     Log.i(TAG, "Adv Manufacturer  utf-8 Data:" + mdata);
   }
}
```

Here I am able to decode utf-8 encoded data. but fails for other encodings. Is there a better way to detect encoding and decode to string ?
I have tried : `org.mozilla.universalchardet.UniversalDetector` to detect encoding but it fails to detect correct encoding. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Nothing says it should be text in the first place. That's probably what you cann "other encodings", it is not text at all.

Comment: Thanks. But is there anyway to get data in human readable form ? Or is it like, only manufacturer can decode it ?

Comment: Manufacturer specific data is freely formed. If you want to implement a generic decoder, you must get specs from all manufacturers, if spec there is.

Comment: Thanks. Is this the case of `service data` in the advertisement data too ?

Comment: It depends on the service. Standard services define standard encodings. Proprietary services are... proprietary!